# noui slider keypress error when change direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

When I set my nouislider to **ltr** as following,it can up and down by keypress smoothly.
http://jsfiddle.net/jeff_chung/L8md5251/

```
<div class="example">
    <div id="keypress" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background">

    </div>
    <input type="text" id="input-with-keypress">
</div>
<script>
    var keypressSlider = document.getElementById('keypress'),
        input = document.getElementById('input-with-keypress');

    noUiSlider.create(keypressSlider, {
        start: 0.66,
        direction: 'ltr',
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min': [0.66, 0.22],
            '14.29%': [1, 0.33],
            '28.57%': [2, 0.67],
            '42.86%': [5, 1.67],
            '57.14%': [10, 3.33],
            '71.43%': [20, 6.67],
            '85.71%': [40, 13.33],
            'max': 80
        }
    });

    keypressSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
        input.value = values[handle];
    });

    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
        keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
    });
    // Listen to keydown events on the input field.
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

        // Convert the string to a number.
        var value = Number(keypressSlider.noUiSlider.get()),
            sliderStep = keypressSlider.noUiSlider.steps()

        // Select the stepping for the first handle.
        sliderStep = sliderStep[0];

        // 13 is enter,
        // 38 is key up,
        // 40 is key down.
        switch (e.which) {
            case 13:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
                break;
            case 38:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(value + sliderStep[1]);
                break;
            case 40:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(value - sliderStep[0]);
                break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

However,if I set it to **rtl**,it cannot up and down when it reach 2 but okay when mouse scrolling
http://jsfiddle.net/jeff_chung/po2rcj7z/1/

```
<div class="example">
    <div id="keypress" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background">

    </div>
    <input type="text" id="input-with-keypress">
</div>
<script>
    var keypressSlider = document.getElementById('keypress'),
        input = document.getElementById('input-with-keypress');

    noUiSlider.create(keypressSlider, {
        start: 0.66,
        direction: 'rtl',
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min': [0.66, 0.22],
            '14.29%': [1, 0.33],
            '28.57%': [2, 0.67],
            '42.86%': [5, 1.67],
            '57.14%': [10, 3.33],
            '71.43%': [20, 6.67],
            '85.71%': [40, 13.33],
            'max': 80
        }
    });

    keypressSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
        input.value = values[handle];
    });

    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
        keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
    });
    // Listen to keydown events on the input field.
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

        // Convert the string to a number.
        var value = Number(keypressSlider.noUiSlider.get()),
            sliderStep = keypressSlider.noUiSlider.steps()

        // Select the stepping for the first handle.
        sliderStep = sliderStep[0];

        // 13 is enter,
        // 38 is key up,
        // 40 is key down.
        switch (e.which) {
            case 13:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
                break;
            case 38:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(value + sliderStep[1]);
                break;
            case 40:
                keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(value - sliderStep[0]);
                break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong with your code, as it follows the example on the noUiSlider page:

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function( e ) {
    // Convert the string to a number.
    var value = Number( keypressSlider.noUiSlider.get() ),
        sliderStep = keypressSlider.noUiSlider.steps()

    // Select the stepping for the first handle.
    sliderStep = sliderStep[0];

    // 13 is enter,
    // 38 is key up,
    // 40 is key down.
    switch ( e.which ) {
        case 13:
            keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
            break;
        case 38:
            keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set( value + sliderStep[1] );
            break;
        case 40:
            keypressSlider.noUiSlider.set( value - sliderStep[0] );
            break;
    }
});
```

It seems to me that there is bug the original noUiSlider code. Following the original example, this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ubr37u5n/ works perfectly, however, changing the direction to **rtl**, causes the same behavior as you are experiencing, and the slider will stuck at value of **300**, as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p6kkr2hv/.

It is somehow connected to the nonlinear settings, when I removed this settings, it started to work with both directions **ltr** and **rtl**, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/a85uvhg8/

Comment: Thanks for the comment.It does looks like the bug of no ui slider.Do you have a idea how to avoid the bug while the nonlinear setting still works?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have fix for that library. I played with it for an hour, but their code is quite big, and in my opinion not very clear. But I saw that you have notified the team about that bug, so I believe they will take a look at it and the will fix it. It seems to me like a problem with rounding the values.

Comment: This bug fix in the latest release, 9.0.0.